# C# add items to comboBox according to other comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I need some help please!
I am doing an app and I have a comboBox where I can choose a specialty(cbSpecialty). I made another comboBox(cbDoctor) and I want to see there just the name of the doctor from that specialty. I tried this code:

```
private void cbDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (cbSpecialty.Text)
            {
                case "Cardiology":
                    cbDoctor.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"Dr. CC","Dr. DD"});
                    break;

                case "General Medicine":
                    cbDoctor.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "Dr. AB" });
                    break;

            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work. When I run the app I choose a specialty ex. Cardiology and in the second comboBox I what to see a list with Dr.CC and Dr.DD but the list is empty. Please help me. What I have done wrong?

Comment: are there any whitespaces at the end in the cbSpecialty.Text?  Have you used the debugger to see if it is hitting one of the case statements?

Comment: When you put in a breakpoint does it call this method? If it runs the method is the `cbSpecialty.Text` what you think it is (ie does it run the correct case of your switch)?

Comment: Is the cbDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged_1 event attached to the right element ? i.e. it should be attached to the cbSpecialty combo box, as the method name goes it looks like the cbDoctor combo box's event

Comment: @AbdulMateenMohammed  Good Catch!!!

Comment: @AbdulMateenMohammed you are right, the event is wrong i switch it at cbSpecialty_SelectedIndexChanged and it works. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your data is added to the items list, but not bind to the combo box.

Use `cbDoctor.DataBind();` after adding the items.